# Get-ADUser not caching results

Tags: powershell

```
$users = get-aduser -filter 'extensionAttribute10 -notlike "*" -and proxyaddresses -like "*"' -Properties extensionAttribute10,proxyaddresses,company

foreach($user in $users){
    $user
}
```

In the above sample the get-aduser commandlet returns ~20,000 objects (and takes some time to run).  Once *Get-ADUser* is complete and the script moves onto the foreach loop, PowerShell seems to call *Get-ADUser* again for each object in the array rather than just returning the values from the variable (and is subsequently really, really slow).

The same behaviour applies if I reference an object in the array by using $users[100] - the first time it is slow to return the user as it makes a call to the Domain Controller, the second time I call it it returns instantly as the result is cached.

Is this expected behaviour, and is there a way of controlling it / caching all results upfront?

PSVersion: 5.1.15063.1563

> **Update**
>   - It seems this only occurs when you're querying objects in a forest which is remote to the user executing the command:

```
$myForest | Get-ADUser -filter * 
$myForest[0]        # <-- this doesn't reach back to a DC to return the user

$remoteForest | Get-ADUser -filter * -server dc1.remoteforest.com
$remoteForest[0]    # <-- this will call back to a DC to fetch the user even though it's 
                    # been successfully retrieved in the previous line
```

Comment: Show us what you _actually_ do inside the loop. Simply emitting the object with the three selected properties (+ the defult properties) would not cause any delay.

Comment: In the example above I still see the delay, I'd purposefully stripped back everything that was in the loop in case it was the loop that was causing the delay.  I even ran procmon while accessing the an item in the array and it makes a call out to the domain controller.  I'm starting to think it might be some kind of environmental issue...

Comment: Having the same issue here. Apparently PS does not cache non-default properties form a remote forest. If you don't specify properties, it does cache it.

Comment: You could save memory with `get-aduser | foreach-object { $_ }`

Answer (score 0):

I have not observed the ActiveDirectory module calling Get-ADUser when the results are referenced in an array. You may be running into a memory issue. I recommend checking the memory allocation settings for PowerShell, and compare with the actual memory utilization when your script is executing.

```
#Start the Win RM service because it is required for the subsequent command.
Get-Service -Name WinRM | Start-Service

#Get the Max Memory Per Shell in MB
$memLimitPerShellMB = Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB

#Write value to console.
$memLimitPerShellMB.Value

#Check PowerShell memory utilization. Capture this information in a separate shell while your other, heavier, process is running.
get-process | Where-Object ProcessName -like "*PowerShell*"

#If needed, the MaxMemoryPerShellMB value can be adjusted using this command:
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB <NEW VALUE>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone runs into this 2 year after original question, this is expected behavior of AD Module. Get-ADUser returns some attributes but omits the other (I have no idea what attributes are returned at first run, understandably it should be those bare minimum attributes, or attributes that don't put too much performance hit on DCs). It won't retrieve those missing attributes until you actually call for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue. There are several workarounds depending on your specifics of your use-case. My particular use-case was the most challenging and I'm sharing what ended up being the best solution for me.

**Use case:**
Perform Use ADModule (Get-AD* cmdlets) to obtain AD Objects and Non-Default/Extended attribute properties within a script that runs from a single server and must query against multiple trusted domains. This means the **-Server** parameter must be utilized.

**Problem:**
There is a bug in the ADModule that causes a slow/performance penalty when using the **-Server** parameter with Get-AD* Cmdlets to obtain Non-Default/Extended attribute prop ties and traversing the results from within a standard **Foreach** loop. This penalty does not occur when using the `| Foreach-Object` pipeline.

**Solution 1:**
Utilize '| Foreach-Object' pipeline with '| Where-Object' Clause to allow for clean breaking/exiting from within the pipeline.

Example:

```
$break = $false
Get-ADGroup -Filter * PipelineVariable adObject -Properties groupType -Server <Your-DC> | Where-Object {-not $break} | ForEach-Object { 
    try{ ...}
    catch{ if($ExceptionYouWantToBreakFrom){ $break = $true}
}
```

- Pros: Very Fast
- Cons: Must account for 30min default [ADWS Query Timeout (MaxEnumContextExpiration)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd391908(v=ws.10)) when performing long running pipeline processing with ADModule cmdlet. Potentially, you can wrap your call in some 'Retry' logic that catches the timeout exception and retries your call.

**Solution 2:**
Utilize standard `Foreach` loop and force eager loading of non-default/extended properties from the pipeline.

Example:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -OutVariable allObjects -Properties groupType -Server <Your-DC> | % { $_.null } | out-null
Foreach($adObject in $allObjects){
  ...
}
```

- Pros: Fairly Fast. Don't need to worry about 30min default [ADWS Query Timeout (MaxEnumContextExpiration)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd391908(v=ws.10))
- Cons: Looks ugly. Some other minor time penalties when making additional Get-AD* cmdlet calls from within the Foreach loop.